# Declared function return does not match the type of the value that is returned (and inferred by the compiler)

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, type-mismatch, winit

I'm trying to get started with [`imgui` ] for Rust (along with [`glutin`] and [`winit`]), and I'm working on creating the event loop ([`glutin`]). To do this, I'm calling `event_loop.run_return()` (not `run()` since I want it to return control once the UI is closed).

According to the docs (`Ctrl+Q` in CLion), the return type of `run_return()` is `i32` (an integer):

```rust
winit::platform::run_return impl<T> EventLoopExtRunReturn for EventLoop<T>
fn run_return<F>(&mut self, event_handler: F) -> i32 where     F: FnMut(Event<'_, Self::UserEvent>, &EventLoopWindowTarget<Self::UserEvent>, &mut ControlFlow),
Initializes the winit event loop.
...
```

When I look at the source, it show the exact same (an `i32`):

```rust
fn run_return<F>(&mut self, event_handler: F) -> i32
```

I want to log what this returns (I'm using [`tracing`]), so I tried to store it as a variable and then print it:

```rust
let exit_code = ui_system
    .event_loop
    .run_return(event_loop_run);

drop(_run_span_entered); //Ignore, tracing

info!("exit_code: {exit_code}");
```

This errors on the `info!()`, because `()` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`[image: () doesn't impolement std::fmt::Display image]

This is pointing at `{exit_code}`, which is most definitely not `()`. *Also note how CLion infers the type of `exit_code` to be `i32`*.

If I try to force the type of `exit_code`, then the `info!()` is happy, but now the variable definition errors out:

```
mismatched types [E0308] expected `i32`, found `()`
```

[image: mismatched types i32/()]

Unless I'm going crazy, this is clearly wrong, because the function definition says it must return an `i32`, but yet the compiler somehow thinks it isn't?

`cargo build` shows the same thing:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  --> src\main.rs:60:25
   |
60 |       let exit_code:i32 = ui_system
   |  ___________________---___^
   | |                   |
   | |                   expected due to this
61 | |         .event_loop
62 | |         .run_return(event_loop_run);
   | |___________________________________^ expected `i32`, found `()`
```

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot help without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the previous version of winit](https://docs.rs/winit/0.26.0/winit/platform/run_return/trait.EventLoopExtRunReturn.html#tymethod.run_return), `run_return()` did return `()`.

I suspect that your `Cargo.toml` specifies `0.26` (or earlier) but CLion is somehow incorrectly presenting you with documentation for `0.27`.

Comment: That would be it, `cargo tree` shows that I'm using `imgui-winit-support v0.8.2 -> winit v0.25.0`, but the path to the source in CLion is `winit v0.27`. Marking as answered, thanks!